# Information about checkout directories in svn

Tags: svn

I have an svn repository, that I used a while back. I am pretty sure that I have some uncommitted changes in a working directory that lies somewhere, on one of my machines. However, I cannot find the working directory (possibly have deleted it by chance).

This seems like a long-shot. Does the repository contain any information about the checked out directories. Specifically, the ip/hostname of the machine that remotely (ssh) checks out the trunk?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the svn repository contains no information about checked out directories. The operation `svn checkout` is basically a read-only operation.

However, you may find information about the clients in other places - depending on how you access the repository. If you access the repository with *http/apache*, you will find the clients including ip addresses in the apache log files. If you access the repository with `ssh`, you may find information in `/var/log/auth`.

Comment: I did manage to trace the ips from the ssh sessions at the time I was interested. Still could not find the working directory. (I declared it deleted  :-( ).

Answer (score 0):

As @nosid says: *No, the svn repository contains no information about checked out directories*  (or uncommitted changes for that matter). However, if you have not deleted your uncommitted data, `svn status` will show all changed / added / unversioned items. Modified items will start with an `M` (run `svn status --help`). So if you run it on all the suspected working copies - maybe you'll get lucky. Sorry in advance if you already know what I've written.